# Syncing HTML5 <video> with <audio> playback

Tags: javascript, html, video, audio

I am having  track from one source, mute, and I'd like to play background music over it using  element. The tracks contain some time critical elements.

What would be the options to sync these two different media players in HTML5 / Javascript?  would give the master clock as it audio playback is very time sensitive - loosing video frames now and then is not critical.

Comment: Currently I do this by setting video.currentTime which I get from the audio track clock https://github.com/miohtama/slideshow9000/blob/master/slideshow/static/video.js#L48

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mikko Ohtamaa provided a solution in a comment, which I actually think is the best option here - it doesn't require a framework, and it doesn't require you to edit your video files.

Essentially, just grab the current time from the video element when it is "unmuted", and apply that time to the audio element.  Some code might look like this:

```
function unmute() {
  var vid = document.getElementById("video");
  var aud = document.getElementById("audio");

  aud.currentTime = vid.currentTime;
  aud.play();

}
```

Comment: Thanks - had not noticed this question is still left open by me :)

Comment: The only problem here is that the video may not be playing yet, in which case `vid.currentTime` will be null.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/honzzyk/c8vrb8qj/) is a simple solution using Popcorn.js inspired by [this](https://bocoup.com/weblog/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos) article.

```js
$(function(){
var medias = {
    audio: Popcorn("#narration"),
    video: Popcorn("#video")
  },
  loadCount = 0,
  events = "play pause timeupdate seeking volumechange".split(/\s+/g); 


// iterate both media sources
Popcorn.forEach(medias, function(media, type) {

  // when each is ready... 
  media.on("canplayall", function() {

    // trigger a custom "sync" event
    this.emit("sync");

    // Listen for the custom sync event...    
  }).on("sync", function() {

    // Once both items are loaded, sync events
    if (++loadCount == 2) {
      // Uncomment this line to silence the video
      //medias.video.mute();

      // Iterate all events and trigger them on the video 
      // whenever they occur on the audio
      events.forEach(function(event) {

        medias.video.on(event, function() {

          // Avoid overkill events, trigger timeupdate manually
          if (event === "timeupdate") {

            if (!this.media.paused) {
              return;
            }
            medias.audio.emit("timeupdate");

            return;
          }

          if (event === "seeking") {
              medias.audio.currentTime(this.currentTime());
          }
          
          if (event === "volumechange") {  
           if(this.muted()) { 
            medias.audio.mute(); 
           } else {
            medias.audio.unmute(); 
           } 
           
           medias.audio.volume(this.volume());
          }

          if (event === "play" || event === "pause") {
            medias.audio[event]();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
});
```

```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.bocoup.com/js/popcorn.min.js"></script>
     
<audio id="narration">
 <source src="https://videos.cdn.mozilla.net/uploads/webmademovies/popcorn101/popcorn101.ogg">
</audio>
<video id="video" controls="controls">  
 <source src="https://videos.cdn.mozilla.net/uploads/webmademovies/popcorntest.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Is it possible to sync in both ways, I mean changing in audio reflects to video and changing in video reflect to audio ?

Comment: When video is paused for loading data, the audio won't stop.

Answer (score 1):

Easy with a very simple trick ;)

```
<video id="myvideo" controls muted loop>
    <source src="sample_video_no_sound.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <audio id="myaudio">
        <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
</video>

<script>
    var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
    var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");

    var change_time_state = true;

    myvideo.onplay = function(){
        myaudio.play();
        if(change_time_state){
            myaudio.currentTime = myvideo.currentTime;
            change_time_state = false;
        }
    }

    myvideo.onpause = function(){
        myaudio.pause();
        change_time_state = true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What if someone decides to skip a minuit of the video?

Answer (score 0):

The same effect can be achieved by including the music in your video file itself. The html5 video player controls will have the ability to mute the sound.

Comment: As I said I specifically need to avoid this: the music is dynamically produced.

Answer (score 0):

Try VideoJS. At the time when the video playback starts when the page is loaded and ready, you are able to trigger a function which would start playing the music that is contained in the page separately.

http://videojs.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable solution. The only html5 feature that supported sync of multiple streams is mediaGroup. It was unshipped by Chrome and deprecated by w3c.