# syncing audio and video on seek

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a different audio file for a video. I currently have them play together on click and same for pause. The problem is seeking how can I sync both audio and video when user seeks the video. Thanks in advance.

```js
var myvideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
myvideo.onplay = function() {
  myaudio.play();
}
myvideo.onpause = function() {
  myaudio.pause();
}
```

```css
video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video id="myvideo" controls muted>
<source src="https://yewtu.be/latest_version?id=ZqyAI1L_Seo&itag=399" type="video/mp4" />
<audio id="myaudio" controls>
  <source src="https://yewtu.be/latest_version?id=ZqyAI1L_Seo&itag=251" type="audio/webm">
</audio>
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syncing HTML5 <video> with <audio> playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433900/syncing-html5-video-with-audio-playback)

Comment: @Dorad im reviewing it

Comment: @Dorad the Popcorn.js solution was decent but as mentioned in the comments When video is paused for loading data, the audio won't stop. Can you think of any solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, didn't find a trivial solution. A super-weapon would be to establish a server-side service which would combine the streams and expose them as a middleware.

Comment: @Dorad Yeah i think that's the best solution. I couldn't get a front end solution too. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't fine a browser-only solution.

You can create a backend service to combine the streams into one. I.E. by using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1587340/merge-audio-and-video-stream-in-ffmpeg) and consume it from browser.